# Some files appear as a red dot in Visual Studio 2019 using Git as version control

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, git-extensions

I am using Git as version control system under Visual Studio 2019.
I am not using the integrated Git that comes with Visual Studio, instead I am using a standalone program called Git Extensions from which I am performing all the Git actions.

I have seen that some files are marked in Visual Studio solution explorer as blue lock (checked in), some others as a red tick (Pending edit) and some others as red dot (ignored).

I am especially worried about those marked as ignored (red dot). Why is it happening?

Below an image:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file? https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @Schwern Yes, it is in the .gitignore file. Sorry I am newbie in Git and this project is not mine. Thx. Also I would like to know one thing that I am not understanding at all and it is: What is the goal of marking them as ignored within .gitignore if in fact they are tracked with an standalone app which is Git Extensions? maybe to avoid conflicts between the git integrated within Visual Studio and the standalone Git Extensions app?

Comment: If I understand [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) correctly, it's nothing but a wrapper around Git. It's just telling you that Git is ignoring that file. Everything is looking at the same Git repository.